# Dispose Linq-to-SQL data context in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-sql

Which should I use to correctly dispose the Linq-to-SQL context in WCF?

Here is my sample interface

```
public interface IMyWebService
{
        [OperationContract]
        List<MyTable> GetMyStuff();
}
```

Here is my `svc.cs`. What is the preferred method of disposing the Linq-to-SQL data context in WCF?

```
public class MyWebService : IMyWebService
{
        public List<MyTable> GetMyStuff()
        {
            IQueryable<MyTable> myTable;

            using (var db = new MyWebServiceDatabaseDataContext())
            {
                myTable = db.MyTable.Select(a => a);
            }

            return myTable.ToList();
        }

        ////OR

        public List<MyTable> GetMyStuff()
        {
            var db = new MyWebServiceDatabaseDataContext();

            var myTable = from a in db.MyTable
                select a;

            return myTable.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd definitely recommend `using(....) { ..... }` - this **ensures** proper disposal at the end of the using block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statements

```
using(var db = new MyWebServiceDatabaseDataContext())
{
        var myTable = from a in db.MyTable
            select a;
        return myTable.ToList();
}
```

It will automatically Dispose your context.This statement converting behind the scenes like this:

```
       try
       {
            var db = new MyWebServiceDatabaseDataContext();
            var myTable = from a in db.MyTable
                          select a;
            return myTable.ToList();
        }
        finally
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
```